# Drag and Drop cards in nodejs + ejs+ express framework

Tags: node.js, express, drag-and-drop, ejs

I am creating an app similar to LeanKit's Kanbanize app. [LeanKit](http://leankit.com/)
Here is my HTML Code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Sign In</title>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/mycss.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script      src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
  <script>
     var onDragEnter = function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#dropzone").addClass("dragover");
    }, 
    onDragOver = function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); 
       if(!$("#dropzone").hasClass("dragover"))
        $("#dropzone").addClass("dragover");
   }, 
onDragLeave = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#dropzone").removeClass("dragover");
},

onDrop = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#dropzone").removeClass("dragover");
    console.log(event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files);
};

$("#dropzone")
.on("dragenter", onDragEnter)
.on("dragover", onDragOver)
.on("dragleave", onDragLeave)
.on("drop", onDrop);
 </script>
 <body style="margin:0; background-color: #F2F2F2;">
   <!--Header--> 
    <div id = "header">
   <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Welcome to Kanban View</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-whatever="Delivery Hours">Add Card</a></li>
      <li><a href="KanbanprojectStatus">Project Status</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
  <div class="container" style="width:900px; height:500px;padding-top:70px;">
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-3">
            <h4>Ready to Start</h4>
            <ul title="Ready to Start" id="lane_192025152_contents" laneid="192025152" style="height: 512px; -webkit-user-select: none;" class="cmVoice  laneContents connectedSortable  ui-sortable" cmenu="menu_LaneBody"> 
                <div draggable="true"><li id="card_192025057" title="Risk / Issue: Q1 Sales Metrics" class="card  cmVoice  {cMenu:'menu_Card'}" cmenu="menu_Card" style="-webkit-user-select: none; cursor: default;">
                      <div class="card-background" style="background-color:#FDD29A;">
                           <div class="little-arrow rootVoice {menu:'menu_Card'} clicked" menu="menu_Card" clicked="clicked" style="white-space: nowrap;"></div>                                                 
                              <div class="card-header" style="background-color:rgb(196,140,67)">
                                  <div class="cardtext elipses" title="test1">Test 1</div>
                              </div>
                           </div>     
                 </li>
                 </div>

                  <div draggable="true"><li id="card_192025057" title="Risk / Issue: Q1 Sales Metrics" class="card  cmVoice  {cMenu:'menu_Card'}" cmenu="menu_Card" style="-webkit-user-select: none; cursor: default;">
                      <div class="card-background" style="background-color:#FDD29A;">
                           <div class="little-arrow rootVoice {menu:'menu_Card'} clicked" menu="menu_Card" clicked="clicked" style="white-space: nowrap;"></div>                                                 
                              <div class="card-header" style="background-color:rgb(196,140,67)">
                                  <div class="cardtext elipses" title="test2">Test 2</div>
                              </div> 
                           </div> 
                 </li>
                 </div>

                 <div draggable="true"><li id="card_192025057" title="Risk / Issue: Q1 Sales Metrics" class="card  cmVoice  {cMenu:'menu_Card'}" cmenu="menu_Card" style="-webkit-user-select: none; cursor: default;">
                      <div class="card-background" style="background-color:#FDD29A;">
                           <div class="little-arrow rootVoice {menu:'menu_Card'} clicked" menu="menu_Card" clicked="clicked" style="white-space: nowrap;"></div>                                                 
                              <div class="card-header" style="background-color:rgb(196,140,67)">
                                  <div class="cardtext elipses" title="test3">Test 3</div>
                              </div>  
                           </div>   
                 </li>
                 </div>

                  <div draggable="true"><li id="card_192025057" title="Risk / Issue: Q1 Sales Metrics" class="card  cmVoice  {cMenu:'menu_Card'}" cmenu="menu_Card" style="-webkit-user-select: none; cursor: default;">
                      <div class="card-background" style="background-color:#FDD29A;">
                           <div class="little-arrow rootVoice {menu:'menu_Card'} clicked" menu="menu_Card" clicked="clicked" style="white-space: nowrap;"></div>                                                 
                              <div class="card-header" style="background-color:rgb(196,140,67)">
                                  <div class="cardtext elipses" title="test4">Test 4</div>
                              </div>
                           </div>     
                 </li>
                 </div>
             </ul>
        </div>

        <div class = "col-md-3">
        <h4>In Progress</h4>
         <div id='dropzone'><ul title="Ready to Start" id="lane_192025152_contents" laneid="192025152" style="height: 512px; -webkit-user-select: none;" class="cmVoice  laneContents connectedSortable  ui-sortable" cmenu="menu_LaneBody"> 
                <li id="card_192025057" title="Risk / Issue: Q1 Sales Metrics" class="card  cmVoice  {cMenu:'menu_Card'}" cmenu="menu_Card" style="-webkit-user-select: none; cursor: default;">
                      <div class="card-background" style="background-color:#FDD29A;">
                           <div class="little-arrow rootVoice {menu:'menu_Card'} clicked" menu="menu_Card" clicked="clicked" style="white-space: nowrap;"></div>                                                 
                              <div class="card-header" style="background-color:rgb(196,140,67)">
                                  <div class="cardtext elipses" title="Attach a Report!">Search Results Page</div>
                              </div>  
                           </div>
                 </li>
        </div>  </div>

        <div class = "col-md-3">
        <h4>Ready for Review</h4>
        <ul title="Ready to Start" id="lane_192025152_contents" laneid="192025152" style="height: 512px; -webkit-user-select: none;" class="cmVoice  laneContents connectedSortable  ui-sortable" cmenu="menu_LaneBody"> 
                 <li id="card_192025057" title="Risk / Issue: Q1 Sales Metrics" class="card  cmVoice  {cMenu:'menu_Card'}" cmenu="menu_Card" style="-webkit-user-select: none; cursor: default;">
                      <div class="card-background" style="background-color:#FDD29A;">
                           <div class="little-arrow rootVoice {menu:'menu_Card'} clicked" menu="menu_Card" clicked="clicked" style="white-space: nowrap;"></div>                                                 
                              <div class="card-header" style="background-color:rgb(196,140,67)">
                                  <div class="cardtext elipses" title="Attach a Report!">Welcome Page</div>
                              </div>  
                           </div>
                 </li>
             </ul>
        </div>

        <div class = "col-md-3">
        <h4>Recently Finished</h4>
        <ul title="Ready to Start" id="lane_192025152_contents" laneid="192025152" style="height: 512px; -webkit-user-select: none;" class="cmVoice  laneContents connectedSortable  ui-sortable" cmenu="menu_LaneBody"> 
                 <li id="card_192025057" title="Risk / Issue: Q1 Sales Metrics" class="card  cmVoice  {cMenu:'menu_Card'}" cmenu="menu_Card" style="-webkit-user-select: none; cursor: default;">
                      <div class="card-background" style="background-color:#FDD29A;">
                           <div class="little-arrow rootVoice {menu:'menu_Card'} clicked" menu="menu_Card" clicked="clicked" style="white-space: nowrap;"></div>                                                 
                              <div class="card-header" style="background-color:rgb(196,140,67)">
                                  <div class="cardtext elipses" title="Attach a Report!">Login Functionality</div>
                              </div>  
                           </div>
                 </li>
             </ul></div>
        </div>
</div>
  <!--Footer--> 
   <div id="footer">
   <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
      <div class="container">
      </div> <!-- container-->
  </div> <!-- navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom" -->
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I added the drag and drop code based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581846/drag-and-drop-using-basic-jquery-framework) question. I can see by cards are dragging but cannot drop to In Progress section. The functionality is I should be able to drag a card from anywhere and drop to any of the 4 sections, based on the number of cards, each section should be responsive so they can fit the new card. Any advice would really be appreciated. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually move the DOM element. Here's one way you could do it:

https://jsfiddle.net/z3o28qut/

```
var dragItem;

// You should make this selector more specific to your card elements
$("div")
    .on("dragstart", function(event) {
        dragItem = $(event.currentTarget).find('li') && $(event.currentTarget).find('li')[0];
    });

onDrop = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#dropzone").removeClass("dragover");

    var ul = $(this).find('ul')[0];
    if (dragItem) {
        ul.appendChild(dragItem);
    }
};
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how I should make this specific to my card elements? Thanks

Comment: My suggestion is attaching a `dragstart` event to all `div` elements, which probably isn't what you want. You should define a class that all of your draggable card elements have in common, eg `<div class='task-card'></div>`. Then you can only listen for dragstart events on them like so: `$('.task-card').on('dragstart', ...)`